# Use mysql in a C# Windows Application within Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio

I want to know the code which allows my C# Windows Application to use mysql database located on internet with C# in a windows application and run main queries such as delete, insert, select,etc. Please Explain like i am a newbie.

Comment: how do you access your mySQL, via IP address? is that your server or your hosting provider server? are you sure the provider allows you to connect to it remotely and not only from a hosted web application?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows application using MySQL from a webserver](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8788094/windows-application-using-mysql-from-a-webserver)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bind the [MySQL .Net Connector](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net) in your project and then you can do something like:

```
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

string dbConnectionString = "SERVER=server_address;DATABASE=db_name;UID=user;PASSWORD=pass;";
MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(dbConnectionString);
connection.Open();
MySqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
command.CommandText = "select name from mytable";
MySqlDataReader Reader = command.ExecuteReader();    
while (Reader.Read())
{
     string name = "";
     if (!Reader.IsDBNull(0))
         name = (string)Reader["name"];
}
Reader.Close();
```

Comment: I Found It Elsewhere But THANKS! Can You Do Me A Great Favour and answer my next problem Too?? :D